# count of "posts flagged for moderator attention" seems inaccurate

Tags: bug

for the past few days, whenever the little yellow status box pops up next to "review",
i've gone to take a look.  invariably, it seems to show a number that is greater
(by 3 or 4) than the number of items actually shown.  (at this moment,
three items are shown, although the number advertised is 6.)

have i lost the ability to count?  or are some items "hidden"?
or has the counting mechanism really gone haywire?

Comment: I experienced the same countless times...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Review flags doesn't match actual flags](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2554/5764)

Comment: definite duplicate, but the "answer" (link to meta.stackoverflow) is distinctly unsatisfying.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I fully agree. I wonder why there aren't more people who *know* the back end answering these questions on Meta. Or, better yet, just tell us what's going on when these clear bugs are present...